# PHP 5.2 - 5.3 upgrade in Solaris 9

Tags: php

I am trying to upgrade PHP 5.2.13 to 5.3.16 in Solaris 9 SPARC box. I have installed many extensions in the current version (5.2.13). The installation of PHP 5.2.13 was through binaries and not through source. The extnesions were installed through source via configure, make, make install commands.

While upgrading, is it enough if I copy over the .so files across to extensions directory or configure them afresh?

Any info is well appreciated.

Thank you
Banu

Comment: I think this question belongs on ServerFault or SuperUser, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Are serverfault, superuser other forums where I should sign up and post the questions?

Comment: Got it, have posted teh same in serverfault... Another question, not related to any software..Is there a way to stop the annoying authentication popup in serverfault?